# Ascync Component for VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous, components

does anyone have any suggestions about a component I could use in my windows forms project to create an async connection with a server? I would need to be able to pass it an IP address, port Number etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connections are typically NOT async.

You create the connection and keep it. They have a high cost of connectivity due to handshaking etc. You CAN if you want, set a very low lease-time to release the connection (i.e. a lease time of 1 second) which will drop the connection again, but that's not really async.

Another thing is to create a connection, and perform asynchronous calls over this connection, which may be what you're after?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes I would like to create a connection and perform asynchronous calls over it.